# primeNG calendar select dates by default

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am working with PrimeNg calendar first time and I am stuck with this thing , I need to use this calendar to show/select some initial dates by default which I am getting from Back-end as an array of dates.
I want to show these dates to users and then further they can click on a date which is being selected/showed by default.
Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's the problem? use [(ngModel)] property for p-calendar. Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, There are only option which you can use is `defaultDate` which accept single `Date`

> defaultDate:  Date: null: Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.

You cannot pass the array of Dates which needs to be selected on initilization, Only options by Primeng Calendar which accept arrays are

- disabledDates
- disabledDays

Comment: Thanks Pardeep , is there any other option to do the same thing in angular app ?
displaying some dates and enable user to select any of them ?

Comment: either you need to use some another datepicker or you need to customize their library itself which is not recommended by community too

Comment: thanks !
can you suggest me any other calendar please with required functionality.